# not able to authenticate access_token comming from flutter app in django using google-oauth2 errors come up like your "credentials are not correct"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, python-social-auth

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@psa()
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    token = request.data.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(token)
    print(request)
    if user:
        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response(
            {
                'token': token.key
            },
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
    else:
        return Response(
            {
                'errors': {
                    'token': 'Invalid token'
                    }
            },
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        )
```

so above is the code

and this is the URL

```
re_path('api/register-by-access-token/' + r'social/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', register_by_access_token),
```

But all the time

`user = request.backend.do_auth(token)`

this thing is giving error that "credentials are not correct"

Answer (score 0):

```
The issue is that Google OAuth access tokens issued to mobile apps are actually ID tokens, not access tokens. They use a different signature and contain user information instead of scope information.
To authenticate with these, you need to use a social auth backend that supports ID tokens, like social-auth-app-django.
In that backend, you would use the auth_by_id_token view instead of auth.
```